# Recommended framework for medical application

Tags: vtk, itk, medical-imaging

I am in the startup process for writing a larger application for medical visualization and interaction. I am considering which pipeline to choose.

MITK: Uses ITK at its core. Algorithms inherit from `itk::Process` and object inherit from `itk::Object` for observers etc.

Slicer: Uses VTK at its core. Algorithms inherit from `vtk::vtkAlgorithm` and objects inherit from `vtk::Object`.

Does anyone have experience with both of the frameworks? Pros and cons.

Thanks in advance